# Is Product object available in all Salesforce Editions?

Tags: package, upload, package-install, editions

I have created an app having access to some object like Account, Opportunity .... and Product.

Now, While creating a Package **Product** is shown as Package Requirement.

So, I am just bother that if any of the Salesforce Edition is not having Product object then this will not allow users to install it.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Like, if we kept Data.com Clean Enable while creating a Package, it comes as a required feature for the app and does not allow us to install in the org where such feature is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Product object is available under Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions.